# openpyxl is removing pivot table while updating the value in sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
evidenceworkbook = load_workbook("Inforce_Validation.xlsx")
sheet_data = evidenceworkbook["BV Cube"]
poldata_D2 = sheet_data['A5']
poldata_D2.value = 1000
evidenceworkbook.save("Inforce_Fire_Validation.xlsx")
```

I have pivot table at `D4,E4` and I am trying to change `A5` value. I tried using `keep_vba=True, data_only=True`, once after the save the existing pivot tables are removing from excel.

Comment: Your post is very little information, please update more information. This helps you avoid being voted.

Comment: From the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook): *"openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name."*. Pivot tables might fall under that category

Comment: openpyxl has had support for pivot tables since version 2.5. It's not clear from this code what the relationship is.

Comment: @CharlieClark I want to update values using openpyxl, which in turn updates the corresponding pivot table data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to using win32com library.

here is a wrapper module i wrote to do specific stuff with pivot tables; it's basically VBA translated to python (record macros and read the VBA, it'll make sense).

```
import os, datetime
import win32com.client as win32
win32c = win32.constants
import sys, datetime

letters = ' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' #space to compensate for index. if letter is a if column is 1

def Pull_excel_workbook(path = '', filename = '', visible = False):
    '''function to run excel on the given filename'''
    if path == '': path = os.getcwd()
    if filename == '': raise FileNotFoundError('Please supply a file')
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.Visible = visible
    try: wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path + filename)
    except: print('Try again\n{}'.format(sys.exc_info()))
    ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    data = list(ws.UsedRange.Value) #2d list of rows and columns
    src = '{}!R1C1:R{}C{}'.format(ws.Name, len(data), len(data[0]))
    return excel, wb, src

    #wb.SaveAs(path + filename)

def Create_pivottable(wb, src, table_name = 'Pivot'):
    '''creates Pivot Table object in the wb in a new Pivot worksheet'''
    ws = wb.Sheets.Add()    #should also change wb.ActiveSheet to the new one.
    ws.Name = table_name
    tname = ws.Name
    starting_point = (4,1)  #row, column
    pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(SourceType = win32c.xlDatabase,
                              SourceData = src)
    try:
        pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination = '{}!R{}C{}'.format(tname, starting_point[0], starting_point[1]),
                            TableName = table_name,
                            DefaultVersion = win32c.xlPivotTableVersion10 #15
                            )
    except:             #not sure if will work...
        print('{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(wb, src, table_name, '{}!R{}C{}'.format(tname, starting_point[0], starting_point[1])))
        #tabledestination format of RN Pivot!R4C1 is not correct format, should be 'RN Pivot'!R4C1
        pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination = '{}!R{}C{}'.format(tname, starting_point[0], starting_point[1]),
                            TableName = table_name,
                            DefaultVersion = win32c.xlPivotTableVersion15
                            )
    wb.Sheets(ws.Name).Select()
    wb.Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(3,1).Select()

def Add_to_Filter(wb, tname, field_name):
    ''' '''
    field = wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(field_name)
    field.Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
    field.Position = 1

def Add_to_Row(wb, tname, field_name, position = 1):
    ''' '''
    field = wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(field_name)
    field.Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
    field.Position = position

def Add_to_Column(wb, tname, field_name, position = 1):
    ''' '''
    field = wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(field_name)
    field.Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
    field.Position = position
    if position > 1:
        text = 'maybe do something here....'
        pass

def Add_to_Value(wb, tname, field_name, alias = '', calculation = 'xlSum'):
    ''' '''
    if type(calculation) is str and calculation in win32c.__dict__['__dicts__'][0]:
        calculation = win32c.__dict__['__dicts__'][0][calculation]
    datafield = wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).PivotFields(field_name)
    wb.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(tname).AddDataField(datafield, alias, calculation)

def LtoC(letter):
    global letters
    col = letters.index(letter)
    return col

def CtoL(col):
    global letters
    letter = letters[col]
    return letter
```

Comment: I don't think openpyxl supports excel pivot tables currently. So I'm using win32com library.

Comment: Here it is anyway and hopefully you or someone else can come up with a better method.

Comment: @ThuấnĐàoMinh Is it possible to update the huge excel with win32com library

Comment: Works slow. However the document can be opened in excel. So the end result is available for the user in excel to start working on. Not great for large amounts of data.
Writing 10,000 rows with 10 columns takes on my computer (core i5) app. 70 seconds.

Comment: @manjari PyExcelerate. This one is first of all fast. It creates the 10,000 rows and 10 columns in just 0.17 seconds. Saving the file however takes 2.2 seconds. By far the fastest option of the three. When I try to save 100,000 rows and 10 columns with this module, the excel data is created in just 1.8 seconds. However saving the file now takes 21.7 seconds. Hence, this module is really fast. You can try this lib.

Comment: @ThuấnĐàoMinh I have gone through PyExcelerate  but i did not find updating xls in it

Comment: @manjari 2 opepyxl and PyExcelerate libraries don't help you to solve the problem. Try to use win32com and if the win32com lib doesn't help you to solve this problem, hope someone will help you. I'm so sorry.

Comment: I am trying to use win32com to update excel but i am getting "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None"

Comment: @manjari  I have investigated on google and it seems this problem is very hard to detect root cause. Try it one last time, when you run the code make sure you have turned off the excel application. Turn off in task manager. I really apologize to you, maybe hope someone will help you. I will always follow this topic.